# trying to use a UIalertcontroller to validate an action in swift

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

Hi I am fairly new to coding with swift so please bear with me if this is a Noob question.

But i am trying to get a UIalertcontroller to implement an action (changing an image) after the UIalertcontroller has checked that the password is correct.

so you press the button, UIalertcontroller pops up, you enter the password, the password is a match, it changes the image.

is all i want it to do!

the problem i have is, that i have coded it up and it works, but it works regardless of what text is put into the text field.

I know this should be a relatively easy thing to do but i have read so mch on UIalertcontrollers it is just a blur of code.

```
class Man_VS_Cocktail : UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var Cocktail_Image: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nil

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }

    @IBAction func Cocktail_check_button(sender: AnyObject) {

        var password_Text: UITextField?

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "One more ticked off", message: "ask the barman to enter the password", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        let tickoff_action = UIAlertAction(title: "sign it off", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            action -> Void in

            if let password = password_Text?.text{

                print("Password == \(password)") 
                self.Cocktail_Image.image = UIImage(named: "riddler_question_marks")

            } else {
                print("No password entered")
            }

        }

        alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (txtpassword) -> Void in
            password_Text = txtpassword
            password_Text!.secureTextEntry = true
            password_Text!.placeholder = ""

        }

        alertController.addAction(tickoff_action)
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

     }   
    }
```

If somebody could show me what I am doing wrong that would be ace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not comparing the password to anything. You need to add a way for your view to access the password that the textField should match to and then compare it here:

```
if let password = password_Text?.text {
    print("Password == \(password)") 
    if password == "YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE" {
        self.Cocktail_Image.image = UIImage(named: "riddler_question_marks")
    }
}
```